# Should I care about bit-endianness when making cross-platform data storing code?

Tags: cross-platform, endianness

When I save some binary data on disk (or memory), I should care about byte-endianness if the data must be portable across multiple platforms. But how about **bit**-endianness? Is it fine to ignore?

I think this is fine to ignore, but there can be some pitfalls, so I like to hear other opinions.

Comment: All modern computers handle `byte` as a minimum unit, and in the unit, all devices already done caring all about bit levels. So I don't need to care about bit-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bits are always arranged **the same way** in a byte, though there are (were) some exotic architectures where a byte was not 8 bit. In modern computing *you can safely assume an 8-bit byte*.

What varies (as you properly noted) is a byte arrangement - that one you should take care of, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Big endian vs. little endian mattered more when PowerPC was prevalent (due to its use by Macs).  Now that major OS (Windows, OS X, iOS, Android) and hardware platforms (x86, x86-64, ARM) are all little-endian, it is not much of a concern.